# Why is my IDE telling me it is wrong to define variables with var in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, scope

I'm relatively new to Javascript. I've been exercising using Webstorm IDE, and I noticed when I define variables using the `var` keyword, my IDE throws a warning :

[image]

Why is it wrong to use `var` in this case ? Is it really ? What's more, this code comes from a tutorial and the instructor always uses `var`. Should I just ignore the warning ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the `Javascript language version` set in your IDE ? I believe it is defaulted to `ECMAScript 6`

Comment: yes you can ignore the warning as you are new to the topic.

Comment: @CRayen you are right, it's ECMAScript 6

Comment: @ashishsingh That's bad advice, OP shouldn't ignore the warning, it exists for a reason. It's better for them to learn these concepts now than ignore them and practice poor JavaScript habits.

Comment: Yes i totally agree,but in this case its not really a warning its a lint configured that way and he is just beginning , so i dont want him to confuse about such things. If it was a warning like unused variable that makes sense but var vs let is more of a practice kind of thing IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not "wrong", otherwise it would be an error, not a warning.

It is just very, very, *very*, **VERY** bad practice. `var` has confusing semantics. If it weren't for backwards-compatibility, it would have been removed from the language long ago.

Like the warning says: you should *always* prefer `const`. Only if it is *absolutely* necessary, use `let`. Never, ever, under any circumstance, use `var`.

Comment: But if I use const, doesn't that mean I won't be able to change the value attributed to the variable ? (wouldn't it be a *constant* and not a *variable* ?)

Comment: Yes. That is the whole point of `const`. And that is why using `const` is a good thing. Things that change between different parts of the code are confusing. Try to avoid that as much as possible. Note that, in fact, none of the "variables" you showed in your question actually "vary".

Comment: If you look closely at the suggestion box in the IDE, it offers you to automatically convert the declaration to a `const`. It doesn't even offer changing it to a `let`, because the IDE is smart enough to see that you never change it. In this particular case, `fs` is referring to a library module and you use functions from that module. It would be really bad if that changed all of a sudden!

Answer (score 0):

I think the IDE thinks that the function is an object, and constants are used for objects, not numbers or strings like variables. This will not effect the code, unless it is urgent that you change it. If it is truly urgent, it will just say what the problem is as an error.

Comment: I would normally use const for objects, so I am not saying thats the exact use.